# Why were Stargate's subtitles redone?

Tags: production, stargate, subtitles, stargate-1994

In Australia, when [Special Broadcasting Service (SBS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Broadcasting_Service) put in subtitles when English is not used (ie. *VS Arashi* and *If You Are the One*) the front is generally yellow and generally at the end of the credits SBS add a subtitle that they did the subtitles eg.

> Subtitles: Special Broadcasting Service 2017

Last Night (29/11/2017) SBS aired [the 1994 *Stargate* Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_(film)) and after Daniel is brought back to life thanks to Ra's Sarcophagus we start to see the subtitles for when Ra, his Jaffa, The people of Abydos and Daniel talk non-english (I assume it's Egyptian given Daniel's previous work when he's brought into the soon to be SGC and Ra's assumed identity of an Egyptian God).

Thing is however is that I have seen the film outside of this broadcast and the font was white and the text was thicker (maybe bold) compared to SBS's subtitles.

Now I am unaware if SBS did *Stargate*'s subtitles before or after the DVD Release (I didn't catch the credits because I changed channels after PCXS2 running Tales of Legendia killed the reception) but either way it seems the subtitles were redone for this movie.

What I am wondering however is why? Both SBS's broadcast and the movie I have are both in English and show these subtitles in the same parts. Doesn't redoing the subtitles cost money in regards to manpower and thus kind of a waste of money to redo them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In modern broadcasting, subtitling is a separate data stream accompanying the audio and video, and it is rendered using whatever font is configure in the subtitling device.

This is a more efficient way to store subtitling information (since it can be stored as text rather than as fully-rendered text) but it definitely means the subtitles can look different depending on the hardware used and how it is configured.

Comment: As an example of this, both VLC Media Player (offline) and Netflix (online) allow you to choose the font/color/size of the subtitles. Thus proving that the subtitles are superimposed over the image, and not part of the actual video (note: sometimes, subtitles are part of the video and therefore not changeable. These are called "hardcoded" subtitles, and is  becoming a thing of the past)